# Facebook JSON array

Tags: php, facebook, json

How do I display the data->name?

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Aasdada",
         "category": "asdasd",
         "id": "2342342342",
         "created_time": "2012-11-28T03:56:00+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=12312"
   }
}
```

I tried this but nothing comes out:

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true);
echo("Hello " . $user->data->name);

//also tried this
echo("Hello " . $user[data]); //did not echo anything
echo("Hello " . $user->data[0]->name); //did not echo anything

$user->data[0]['name'] //still no luck
```

What could be the problem?
Anyways my code works with data that is not in array.

I'm just trying to make a simple if user liked page or not.
If data has no contents it means the user has not liked the page.
If it has data then it means the user has liked the page.

--edit--

So tried this out:

```
array(2) { ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(28) "Aasdda" ["category"]=> string(5) "asdad" ["id"]=> string(15) "3123123123" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2012-11-28T03:56:00+0000" } } ["paging"]=> array(1) { ["next"]=> string(245) "https://graph.facebook.com/100023123123" } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$user['data']['0']['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $user->data[0]['name']
```

Comment: Hello didn't echo anything.

Comment: I can see by your output that sinister frogs should be correct.